# How do I configure a Visual Studio Setup project to automatically open the application's Start Menu folder after installation?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition.  The application is a WPF application for .NET 4.0 Client.

Comment: Please... please... don't do this to your users.

Comment: Why? And more importantly, why not just give the user an option to start the program automatically when the installation finishes?

Comment: What's the point of Stack Overflow if people decide what the OP should and should not do?  The question is very legit in some cases and would be interesting to know how to do this. Let the OP decide how to fashion their own creation.

Comment: @BeemerGuy: You should read Raymond Chen (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/). He has countless stories of the nightmares that the Windows development team have had to deal with because programmers decide how to fashion their own creations. Now I'm not saying that opening a folder during installation falls under that category, I'm just reacting to your statement.

Comment: @Mehrdad Afshari: Why not?  I didn't want to implement this too but I don't have sufficient evidence to support my position.

Comment: @Beemer: "Don't do this" doesn't mean "It shouldn't be answered"

Comment: @Chry: I remember many setups that did this back in Win98 era.  Nowadays, less people do this.  I always hate setups that open unnecessary windows without asking (even if they ask but by default, it's selected). The point is, modern Windows versions have better means of putting newly installed apps under spotlight by highlighting them in start menu. Opening start menu folder doesn't really help your users achieve anything.  Most of the time they'll have to close an unnecessary window. More importantly, a good setup should probably let the user choose not to create a start menu folder.